# How to Run a PHP file when files exist in directory - Encoding Server

Tags: php, file, encoding, cron, video-encoding

I'm making an encoding server and need a little help

I have a directory called uploaded, and a php file called videoConverter.php and when it runs It has a loop that will convert all the video files in the uploaded directory and FTP the completed file to a streaming sever.

There is no problem with the script but the problem is once the loop is finished it won't convert any new files uploaded after the loop ends. I need to find away to execute the php file or script when files are uploaded to the uploaded directory.

I was thinking about using a cron job and running the php file every second, but wouldn't it keep running the script while it's already running?

Does anyone know a good way to approach this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't stick with PHP for such a task, it would just be an inefficient layer between the encoding tools and the files themselves - you need an event-driven tool, not a scripting language.

I'd better look at [inotify](http://inotify.aiken.cz/) for local changes in the upload folders, then process new files on the go.

My first take would be using [inotify wrapper](https://github.com/c4milo/node-inotify) in a **Node.js** environment:

- whenever a new file appears, `encode(newFile)` is called;
- when encoding process is finished, `pushToFTP(encodedFile)` callback is fired and transfer begins.

Bonus, smaller files don't have to wait till the whole job finishes due to asyncronous js architecture.

Comment: I couldn't agree with you more, I don't want to stick with PHP, I'm using it because I know that language best..at the moment and I need to get this done, but I will look into that. I'm using Ubuntu server with ffmpeg to encode. So your suggesting I use Node.js and inotify to complete this task?

Comment: Yes, after you manage to log "Hey, file foo.bar added to watched folder" in the console, it's just a matter of writing a couple of functions - plus you learned a nice thing meanwhile.

Comment: Ok great, thanks for your help, if I have any questions about node, I'll make a new question to help benefit the user base, but will drop the URLs here.

Comment: I can't get it to work  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12114142/cant-get-inotify-to-work-using-node-js

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

1. Script wakes up from cron, checks for 'pid' file.
2. If it finds a pid file, it shuts down
3. If it does not find a pid file, it writes it's pid in the current directory.
4. It then begin to process the video file.
5. When complete, or on any failure where it must exit, it removes/unlinks the pid file.

Now, this could create an issue if the process fails and never unlinks the fail, no other jobs would run.

The other thing you could do is have a bootstrap script execute, exec('ps aux | grep VIDEO_SCRIPTNAME'); (or something), and if you see the script is already running, don't execute the video conversion script. In that example you'd have two files, the bootstrap that gets run by cron and checks if the video conversion is currently happening, and the second file, the one that actually does the work.